# How to change React app home title when I change the title tag, its not showing in the browser

Tags: reactjs

I have edited the title inside public folder index.html page but it still not changing in the live site. But I can see the change in local env.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was problem with jenkins pipleline. I didn't know jenkins file wasn't getting updated when we switch branches.